# Is c++ conformance use decltype to help on template deduction?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, decltype

Given this two function:

```cpp
template <typename T> void Print1( const T& aValue, const T& aDefaultValue )
{
    if( aValue != aDefaultValue ) std::cout << aValue << std::endl;
}

template <typename T> void Print2( const T& aValue, const decltype(aValue)& aDefaultValue )
{
    Print1<T>( aValue, aDefaultValue );
}
```

I see that almost in gcc 9 type deduction works always on `Print2` but not on `Print1`

```cpp
unsigned int i = 0;
Print1( i, 0 ); // dont work (cant do type deduction)
Print2( i, 0 ); // work
```

Is this `decltype` technique c++ conformance and why?

Comment: In C++20, you might use [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity): `std::type_identity_t<const T&> aDefaultValue`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [template_argument_deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts), in non-deduced contexts:

> In the following cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that are used to compose P do not participate in template argument deduction
>
> [..]
>
> 2) The expression of a decltype-specifier:

So in

```
template <typename T> void Print2(const T& aValue, const decltype(aValue)& aDefaultValue)
```

type of `aDefaultValue` is non deducible.
`T` is only deduced from `aValue`.

In C++20, alternative is to use [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity):

```
template <typename T>
void Print2(const T& aValue, std::type_identity_t<const T&> aDefaultValue);
```